# Hikari connections and active AS400 jobs

Tags: java, database, ibm-midrange, hikaricp

I am using Hikari connection pool manager to query some tables in an AS400 machine.

I've set a minimum of 1 connection pool connections and a maximum of 10. I am querying 5 tables at the same time.

The problem is that despite using **HikariDataSource getConnection()** method before querying and using **Connection close()** method after each query, when I go to **WRKACTJOB** I see 10 active jobs, presumably one per connection until max connection pool connections are reached.

How do I get clear the unused connections\jobs?

Thank you

Comment: The connections are open. That's what a connection pool does.

Comment: No, I want the connections to be removed from the connection pool after the connection is closed. I don't mind having 10 connections when the tables are being queryed. What I want is those connections removed after the queries

Comment: Without seeing a copy of your WRKACTJOB results, it's hard to be sure of anything. (Screen text is better than a screen image.) From the minimal detail in your question, it sounds like all is as it should be. A connection does require a "job"; but seeing a job remain does not mean any connection exists. Normally, sites wouldn't want the jobs to end just because a connection closes. Other connections might re-use jobs so that full job-start/job-end doesn't happen just because a connection is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a connection pool is to remove the overhead of establishing connections to the database.  It does this by maintaining a "pool" of constantly alive connections, ready for use.

If your workloads are "spikey" with long periods of no activity, but occasional periods of lots of activity, I would suggest setting an idleTimeout of, for example, 1 minute (60000ms).  If you set minimumIdle to 0 as well, then after your periodic workload completes, connections will all be closed within approximately one minute.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the connections to be removed from the connection pool after the connection is closed... I want those connections removed after the queries.

I understand. Don't use a Connection pool. By design, a connection pool will keep a pool of open (and available) `Connection`(s). For the behavior you want, use a regular unpooled [DataSource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasource#Sun.27s_DataSource_Overview_.5B2.5D).